# Лучший способ сказать о ошибке в Си

Tags: c

Пишу небольшую библиотеку, с функциями, которыми кто-то будет пользоваться. В функциях случаются ошибки, о которых нужно каким-то образом сообщить. Казалось бы — банальная вещь, но везде сделано по-разному. Мне интересны преимущества каждого способа, их для меня пока три:

- Возвращать `true` или `false`. Пользователь библиотеки сам будет проверять возвращаемое значение и в зависимости от него выводить сообщение об ошибке.
- Самостоятельно в функциях библиотеки сообщать в подробностях о всех предупреждениях или ошибках, `exit`'ом убивать приложение, ничего не возвращая.
- Возвращать `true` или `false`, но при этом ещё и записывать ошибку в специальный буфер. Пользователь библиотеки может узнать об ошибке, вызвав функцию `GetError()`. Так сделано в *SDL*.

По-моему, лучше всего использовать второй способ, но зачем тогда *SDL* усложняет всё своими `GetError`/`SetError`? Зачем тот же *EGL* возвращает только код ошибки? Прошу сказать о плюсах/минусах того или иного способа, они ведь наверняка есть.

Comment: Второй способ хорош:) особенно если Вы будете убивать приложение в тихую. Используйте обычное соглашение с кодами возврата, старайтесь, что бы во всей библиотеке они были бы одинаковые. GetError - хороший способ возвратить ошибку. А вот в консоль писать ошибки можно (иногда даже и нужно), но главное, что бы это было настраиваемо (например, через вызов какой-то функции или env переменную).

Comment: Второй способ ужасен. Может пользователя вообще не особо волнует успешность вызова функции и есть куча того, что следовало бы сохранить перед завершением. А ты ему раз и exit.

Comment: А я считаю что любой из способов хороший, но каждый для своей задачи. В одних случаях false/true достаточно, в других кода ошибки, а в третьем случае нужно описание, а в четвертом файл с дампом. И правильного ответа нету.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

При написании библиотечного кода надо иметь в виду, что пользоваться этим кодом могут совершенно разные приложения. Поэтому вывод куда-либо явного сообщения об ошибке может просто не сработать, т.к. этого "куда-либо" может вовсе не существовать в текущем окружении (об этом уже упомянул @AntonShchyrov в своем ответе). Более того, язык сообщения может быть вовсе не подходящим для пользователя.

Наиболее подходящим вариантом будет предоставить дополнительную функцию или переменную, откуда можно получить код/текст последней ошибки. Существующие варианты такого подхода это [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) и т.п. В этом случае, пользователь библиотеки может сам решить куда ему следует (и следует ли вообще) выводить сообщение об ошибке.

Отсюда же вытекает и решение о недопустимости вызова `exit` из библиотечного кода. По крайней мере, если нет соответствующей функции в библиотеке, которая меняет это поведение (по умолчанию никаких активных `exit` быть не должно). Пользователю может быть вообще хочется наплевать на обработку ошибок и просто работать дальше, а библиотека рушит ему всё приложение из N потоков на корню.

Возвращать из каждой функции признак успешности её выполнения через `return` может быть не совсем удобно, т.к. в первую очередь функция должна возвращать то, на что она заточена, а не признак ошибки или код возврата. Для примера, представьте, как будет выглядеть функция типа `strlen` в таком случае и насколько удобно будет ей пользоваться при этом.

В любом случае, способы оповещения пользователя библиотеки об ошибочных ситуациях должны быть чётко прописаны в руководстве.

Comment: Добавлю ещё вариант обработки ошибок в стиле GLib: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html - там же и довольно поучительный дисклаймер, о том, какие ошибки следует возвращать, а на каких падать.

Comment: Добавлю к тому, что написал 'alexolut' два пункта: **Первое** - Ваша функция может использоваться внутри демона (сервиса) где любой вывод, куда либо невозможен в принципе. Надо иметь это в виду. **Второе** - Относительно безопасный способ выдачи информации об ошибке непосредственно из функции - в syslog. Если при открытии сислога задать идентификатор программы, то пользователь легко сможет найти все сообщения об ошибках из отлаживаемой программы. Это очень облегчает отладку.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Лучше всего третий способ. Куда во втором способе Вы будете выводить сообщение? В консоль? А если библиотека запущена из оконного приложения? В MessageBox/окно? А если библиотека используется в службе или потоке без очереди сообщений?